# Insert into table from table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
ID uniqueidentifier,
ID2 uniqueidentifier
)
```

...insert into @t
...do stuff to @t

`INSERT INTO testTable (Id, Id2) VALUES (SELECT ID, ID2 from @t)` -does not work?

Comment: Just think of it as a normal table, you can do the usual `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you should do that:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (Id, Id2)
SELECT ID, ID2 
from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
INSERT INTO testTable SELECT ID, ID2 from @t
```