# How to Use the OUTPUT of an Insert Query for another insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert 2 records into 2 tables by using a subquery, but it gives me a syntax error.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The query that I'm trying to execute is

```
INSERT INTO [Files] ([FileTransformationId],[FileTypeEnumId]) 
VALUES 
(
   (INSERT INTO [FileTransformations] OUTPUT INSERTED.FileTransformationId DEFAULT VALUES),
   2
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No idea what you want... Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What I want is to insert a record into a table and insert a second record into another table with the autoincremental id from the first statement in a single statement

Comment: Read about [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT` and `@@IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the output in a variable first. So, I think you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @variable TABLE (value INT)--change type depending on your need

INSERT INTO [FileTransformations] 
OUTPUT INSERTED.FileTransformationId INTO @variable(value)
VALUES(.....)

INSERT INTO [Files] ([FileTransformationId],[FileTypeEnumId]) 
SELECT value, 2 FROM @variable
```

See [How do I use an INSERT statement's OUTPUT clause to get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value) for more info on using output variables and [Insert into table from table variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773903/insert-into-table-from-table-variable) for then inserting from that table variable.

Another option, if you just want the id of the last inserted record is to use [`scope_identity()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide). So you could write the above as:

```
INSERT INTO [FileTransformations] 
VALUES(.....)

INSERT INTO [Files] ([FileTransformationId],[FileTypeEnumId]) 
VALUES scope_identity(), 2
```

Comment: if I try to execute the insert statement with the into clause, it gives me the error Must declare the table variable "@variable", so i guess it needs to be a temp table or should it be possible for @variable to be a simple int variable?

Comment: @variable must be a table variable

Comment: Yes, I missed that @DenisRubashkin, not something I use often

Comment: @Ronald, yes, sorry. I got the syntax for the table variable output wrong

Comment: Any there any performance drawbacks for using the table variable?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It really depends, you'd have to measure your particular scenario @CardinalSystem